# How to avoid metamask confirmation in web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to call following function from my solidity contract using web3js frontend.

```
function playerData(address player) public {      
   gameStatus[player] = false;      
}
```

webjs calls this method using following line of code.

```
 await myContract.methods.playerData(playerAddress)
                .send(
                    { 
                        from: playerAddress,
                    }
                )
```

Now when this line is executed, metamask window opens up and waits for confirmation. As there is no token transfer involved in this method, I want to remove confirmation step of metamask.

Please help me understand if there is a way to call this method without confirmation popup from metamask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to change the state of the blockchain ( modify a State variable ), you'll need to create a transaction, and since transactions are signed by a user you'll need a wallet ( in this case metamask ) to confirm that transaction.

Metamask is a wallet, a simple app ( be it browser extension or physical USB ) that allows someone to interact with a blockchain account using a private key, in this case you use the wallet to sign the transaction and paying for the gas fees.

If you are NOT changing any State variable, just make your functions `view` or `pure` and you won't get the pop-up for metamask.

Now, if you DO change a State variable, the only way you could do it without using metamask is by getting a web3js account object from a private key, and manually signing it with this account ( [check out this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount) ), now I heavily advise against this unless you know what you're doing, because if you publish your private key somewhere, anyone will be able to access your account.

Comment: thank you for the details. Is it possible to get private key from the connected wallet address? If that is possible I do not have to use private key of owner account saved to .env or some other file.

Comment: No, there is no way to get the private key of an account using any library ( like web3js ) from any wallet ( like metamask ), this is because the private key is the "password" to the account, and the wallet wont be secure if they could freely provide the private key of their users to any website wouldn't they? So if you do so, the only way of doing it is by using your OWN account's private key, now if you're toying with frontend DO NOT do it, there is NO way of safely storing secrets on websites, the only "good" way would be the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008529/11269158

Comment: I am right now using owner account from .env of my frontend and have avoided the confirmation window of metamask. As I understand this is not secure way of implementing... 
How about have a dedicated moderator account to call this function based on access modifier and do not have access to any other contract functions. 
Do you suggest this approach as an alternate?

Comment: I still didn't grasp your last comment intention, you mean to restrict a `view` or `pure` function so that when its called it can be only called by the address with the private key you're using? Also, if you use your private key on your frontend ( website ), even if you use a .env your bundled app will still contain the value of the env variable.

Comment: My intention is to remove user interaction to confirm a transaction where we need to update a state variable. No, I cannot use a view or pure function as this one make changes to state variables. I will use external or public on a send transaction. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: If what you wish is to have a smart contract that requires no gas interaction then i'd suggest you reevaluate the project you're working on because a private blockchain would fit more of those requirements. Now back in Ethereum, the only proper way of accomplishing this is by creating an external script that interacts with your wallet, and having the frontend call this script securely, like the example, I've liked before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008529/11269158 , yet, again, if its a big project, I suggest you use a private blockchain such as hyperledger fabric or different.

Comment: But in the end, if all you want is to experiment, then you can freely try to implement the example previously mentioned.

Comment: Thank you MrFrenzoid. 
As of now I am only experimenting but in coming months I have a bigger p2e project shaping up and all these are my learning to make it happen. I will go ahead and do what makes my project more secure.